# RestKit 0.20 nested Object mapping (path to object tree different)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

I got a problem with mapping a nested object value.

I got two objects with the following properties:
a)

```
class Input
@property NSString value;
@property NSString title;
```

b)

```
class Profile
@property Input myAwesomeInput;
```

..so a Profile contains an Input object. When I mapp the objects with RestKit (0.20) I get sth. like this:

```
{ myAwesomeInput_test:{"value":"xyz","title":"a title"}}
```

**What I wanna achieve is:**

```
{myAwesomeInput_test:"xyz"}
```

So I don't want to map "Input" but just the Input.value. Is that even possible?

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
RKObjectMapping* inputMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[inputMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"value"]];

RKRequestDescriptor *reqDescInput = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:inputMapping objectClass:[Input class] rootKeyPath:nil];

RKObjectMapping* searchProfile = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
RKRequestDescriptor *reqDescSearchProfile = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:searchProfile objectClass:[SearchProfile class] rootKeyPath:nil];

[searchProfile addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"myAwesomeInput" toKeyPath:@"myAwesomeInput_test" withMapping:inputMapping]];
```

**EDIT: (solved)**

Ok I solved it. Hope it's the way people should do it. You can directly address from within the dictionary.

```
RKObjectMapping* searchProfile =  [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[aeSearchProfile addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
        @"myAwesomeInput.value": @"myAwesomeInput_test"
}];

RKRequestDescriptor *reqDescSearchProfile = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:searchProfile objectClass:[SearchProfile class] rootKeyPath:nil];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use keypaths rather than multiple mappings.
Try this:

```
RKObjectMapping* searchProfile = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[searchProfile addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"myAwesomeInput.value" : @"myAwesomeInput_test" }];

RKRequestDescriptor *reqDescSearchProfile = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:searchProfile objectClass:[SearchProfile class] rootKeyPath:nil];
```

Comment: thanks, I guess we found/posted the answer at the same time (look at the time posted :D Anyway this will be a good&fast way for others who have the same probe. thanks again